# Viewbox makes WindowsFormsHost disappear in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, viewbox, windowsformshost

I have a WPF project where I maintain video ratio, by placing video control inside a ViewBox.  The video control is a WinForms object wrapped inside a WindowsFormsHost.  I also added a gridSplitter to resize the ViewBox.  It all worked great, until I noticed a strange bug.  When I would use the gridSplitter control to minimize the ViewBox close to zero, the video ratio would get screwed up after expanding it again.  And when I used gridSplitter to contract the ViewBox all the way down to 0, the WindowsFormHost would completely disappear after expanding (it's still there, but it's ActualWidth and ActualHeight are now 0).

Removing the ViewBox control, and just using WindowsFormsHost works fine, but I need the ViewBox to control the aspect ratio.  If I can't find a solution, I will have to control the ratio myself as a workaround.

I figured I must be doing something wrong, so I wrote a quick test program that reproduces the problem.  I will post a link to the complete program below (it's in C#, VS2008).

In the test program I create a grid with two columns with a gridsplitter that lets you resize them.  I then place a ViewBox in the left control and place a WindowsFormsHost inside it.  I then host a red _winFormsButton inside the WindowsFormsHost.

The button scales fine, until you completely contract the left column and then expand it again.  The button is gone.  How do I prevent that from happening, so the button continues to scale after contracting and expanding left column?  Thanks.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DisappearingHost.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>        
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="gridSplitter1" Width="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />        
        <Viewbox>
            <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Button _winFormsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _winFormsButton.Text = "I disappear!";
            _winFormsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            _winFormsButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            windowsFormsHost1.Child = _winFormsButton;
        }
    }
```

Sample code output:
[image]

Link to test project code (VS2008):
[code](http://www.filedropper.com/disappearinghost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of the Viewbox, and controlling WidowsFormHost dimensions myself.

Answer (score 0):

Place your grid splitter in Column zero, so you won't have WPF layout fight. Here is the modified code (notice Grid Splitter column, horiz alignment, and view box margin):

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="gridSplitter1" Width="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <Viewbox Margin="10">
            <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Viewbox>
```

You can make the ViewBox margin just on the right to make it look better

Comment: Moving the GridSplitter won't fix the problem.  In my production code I have GridSplitter control placed in it's own column (it's the recommended practice), and the problem still happens.

Comment: Just for the hell of it, I tried your changes and as suspected, it doesn't work.  The problem is that once the Viewport is minimized to 0 it the winformsHost never recovers.

Comment: @Eternal21 - I'm confused. You marked the answer as being a solution, yet your comments suggest otherwise. Did this get resolved?

Comment: @flamebaud You're right, I forgot to post the correct answer. Fixed now.  The Viewbox was causing the problems, and after a while I gave up on trying to figure why exactly.  It was easier to get rid of it and simply control the aspect ratio myself.