# How to show a WinForms Window in a WPF Grid or Viewbox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In xml file:

```
<Viewbox name="viewbox1"></Viewbox>
```

In C# code-behind:

```
windowformClass window1 = new windowformClass(); // this is the WinForms object, not WPF
viewbox1.Child = window1;
```

When I assign window1 to viewbox1 it shows an error that cannot convert window form to System.Window.ElementUI

What's the right way to do that?

Comment: You need to use WindowsFormsHost for this task

Comment: can you give me any example for this>

Comment: You should avoid using `WindowsForms` in a `WPF` application - if needed use the `WindowsFormsHost` as mentioned by others. Why not just refactor the `WinForm` into `WPF` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use WPF's interop host control for WinForms called WindowsFormsHost.
The code below was extracted and adapted from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Create the interop host control.
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
    new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

// Create your control.
windowformClass window1 = new windowformClass();

// Assign the control as the host control's child.
host.Child = window1;

// Set the interop host control as the ViewBox child.
viewbox1.Child = host;
```

[A user reported a problem with hosting the WindowsFormHost inside a ViewBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748935/viewbox-makes-windowsformshost-disappear-in-wpf). You should check that out in case you have problems with that too.

As you are (apparently) a newcomer, I'd like to give you a little tip:
There are plenty of resources on this subject on both MSDN and SO that could be found through a simple search on your favourite search engine.
Next time, try to find a solution before posting a question, as to keep only the best answers on the topic and save the moderators the work of closing questions as duplicates.
For more on that, check the [help from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)